# shall I use ReactJS in a web SPA App when Vanilla can do the job?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have built a good performing web SPA App using Vanilla JS; the question is:
should I switch to react or continue to use vanilla when it can do the entire job smoothly?
when yes, then should I rebuild everything again with react or just use it for the new parts of the project?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in switching.
Everything that "REACTJS" can, vanilla JS can do too.

REACTJS makes things easier, but if you're good in Vanilla, stick with it!

It can not be more powerful ;)